# tq_get: error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as_date'

Tags: r, tidyquant, golem

When I try to use `tq_get` in `{golem}` I get the Warning:

> Warning: x = 'SPY', get = 'stock.prices': Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)): error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as_date': object '_lubridate_C_valid_tz' not found

And `tq_get` does not return anything.